# How can I clean up my Java Streams?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-stream

I have this stream, as well as quite a few others, where I abuse a bunch of calls to get the job done. Seems like an anti-pattern when taking advantage of J8.

```
+    Arrays.stream(resources)
+        .map(this::ingestFromFile)
+        .collect(Collectors.toList())
+        .stream()
+        .map(Container.class::cast)
+        .map(Container::getAll)
+        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
+        .collect(Collectors.toList())
+        .forEach(
+            dataType -> {
+              loaderConstants.getRepo(dataType.toString()).save(dataType);
+              LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Saved: " + dataType);
+            });
```

How can I shorten this up and what pitfalls should I look out for in the future to avoid this type of development?

Comment: If this code works, this question might be more fitting for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is the point of `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()`?

Comment: As well as `.collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach()`

Comment: This looks like it would be easier to read if it used loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you don't need the intermediate  `.collect(Collectors.toList())` calls as it's unnecessary and causes avoidable overhead.

```
Arrays.stream(resources)
     .map(this::ingestFromFile)
     .map(Container.class::cast)
     .map(Container::getAll)
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .forEach(
            dataType -> {
              loaderConstants.getRepo(dataType.toString()).save(dataType);
              LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Saved: " + dataType);
     });
```

Then you can extract the body of the `forEach` to a method to simplify the pipeline.

Comment: Or replace multiple `map` calls with a lambda: `.flatMap(r -> ((Container) ingestFromFile(r)).getAll().stream())` *(less code + less overhead = Concise and faster)*

Comment: @Andreas nice, this is kinda what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

*My name is Andy, and I don't like streams.*

And this code is a great example of why. (OK, they are sometimes helpful; but really only in very simple cases).

One thing that you (hopefully) learn very early on in programming is that identation makes your code readable: it helps you understand where things happen on related values.

In streamy code, indentation goes right out of the window. That left-hand margin is straight - see how all the periods line up:

```
+    Arrays.stream(resources)
+        .map(this::ingestFromFile)
+        .collect(Collectors.toList())
+        .stream()
+        .map(Container.class::cast)
+        .map(Container::getAll)
+        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
+        .collect(Collectors.toList())
+        .forEach(
+            dataType -> {
+              loaderConstants.getRepo(dataType.toString()).save(dataType);
+              LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Saved: " + dataType);
+            });
```

There is just no visual structure to it.

Especially as this is using `forEach`, it would just be easier to use loops.

```
for (var resource : resources) {
  var fromFile = resource.ingestFromFile();
  var container = (Container) fromFile;
  for (var dataType : container.getAll()) {
    loaderConstants.getRepo(dataType.toString()).save(dataType);
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Saved: " + dataType);
  }
}
```

(You may not be using Java 10; but I don't know the data types anyway. Fill in type types instead of `var` if you need it).

Personally, I think that is *way* easier to read. And it's shorter.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's somewhat of a religious war at my office as well (Streams vs No Streams). I'm trying to get better at using them, but it's even apparent to me when I'm doing something that is hard to read.